# Creating an ImmutableMap<P,ImmutableMultimap<C,V>> stream Collector

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, guava, java-stream

I am frequently running into situations where I need a map of multi-maps for the sake of efficiency. I'd prefer to use Guava's `ImmutableMap` and `ImmutableMultimap` to accomplish this.

I have borrowed and created several `Collector` implementations for Guava so I can leverage Java 8 streams. For example, here is a collector for an `ImmutableListMultimap`.

```
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableListMultimap<K, V>> toImmutableListMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {

    Supplier<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>> supplier = ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::new;

    BiConsumer<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>, T> accumulator = (b, t) -> b
            .put(keyMapper.apply(t), valueMapper.apply(t));

    BinaryOperator<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>> combiner = (l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build());

    Function<ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<K, V>, ImmutableListMultimap<K, V>> finisher = ImmutableListMultimap.Builder::build;

    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}
```

I would like to create a very similar Collector for my current problem. I want my collector to create an `ImmutableMap<P,ImmutableMultimap<C,V>>`, where `P` is the parent key of the main map and `C` is the child key of the child map. Two `Function` lambdas would be provided to map these keys for each `T` item.

This is much easier said than done. All I did productive so far is create the method stub.

```
public static <T, P, C, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<P, ImmutableMultimap<C,V>>> toPartitionedImmutableMultimap(
            Function<? super T, ? extends P> parentKeyMapper,
            Function<? super T, ? extends C> childKeyMapper,
            Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {

}
```

Because the Guava immutable collection builders do not allow lookups, I found myself using mutable hashmaps to be able to look up previously captured values so I would only create a new ImmutableMultimap when the P key was absent. But this process became dizzying very quickly.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the straightforward approach?

```
collectingAndThen(
        groupingBy(
                parentKeyMapper,
                toImmutableListMultimap(childKeyMapper, valueMapper)
        ),
        ImmutableMap::copyOf
);
```

**Update:** Above code works fine with JDK but Eclipse compiler is complaining about it.  Here's a version that Eclipse will accept:

```
public static <T, P, C, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<P, ImmutableMultimap<C, V>>> toPartitionedImmutableMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends P> parentKeyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends C> childKeyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {

    return Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                    parentKeyMapper,
                    SO29417692.<T,C,V>toImmutableListMultimap(childKeyMapper, valueMapper)
            ),
            ImmutableMap::<P,ImmutableMultimap<C,V>>copyOf
    );
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, and want it to work. I'm trying to figure out the compile error with the generics...

Comment: @ThomasN. This compiles fine with java 1.8.0_25.  Are you perchance using eclipse compiler?

Comment: How did you know? lol. Why whats wrong with Eclipse? Besides it being a buggy IDE?

Comment: Eclipse compiler has issues with type inference.  I don't use it, so I don't know much about its issues.  I fiddled with type hints until eclipse stopped complaining.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: We ran some tests using this collector on a couple hundred thousand objects with a dozen properties driving the hashcode/equals. The process went from 15 minutes to 4 seconds. Thanks for all your help. This was huge for us.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a way to use the Guava builders for the outer map, either. Yet involving the mutable hashmaps isn't really that dizzying, is it?
Using the ImmutableMap.Builder and your toImmutableListMultimap, one easily gets an ImmutableMap-Collector.
This can be used in the finisher for the inner multimap yielding the following code:

```
public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K, V>> toImmutableMap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {
    final Supplier<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>> supplier = ImmutableMap.Builder::new;

    final BiConsumer<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>, T> accumulator = (b, t) -> b
            .put(keyMapper.apply(t), valueMapper.apply(t));

    final BinaryOperator<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>> combiner = (l, r) -> l
            .putAll(r.build());

    final Function<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>, ImmutableMap<K, V>> finisher = ImmutableMap.Builder::build;

    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}

public static <T, P, C, V> Collector<T, Map<P, ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<C, V>>, ImmutableMap<P, ImmutableMultimap<C, V>>> toPartitionedImmutableMultimap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends P> parentKeyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends C> childKeyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper) {
    final Supplier<Map<P, ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<C, V>>> supplier = HashMap::new;

    final BiConsumer<Map<P, ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<C, V>>, T> accumulator = (
            map, element) -> map.computeIfAbsent(
            parentKeyMapper.apply(element),
            x -> ImmutableListMultimap.builder()).put(
            childKeyMapper.apply(element), valueMapper.apply(element));

    final BinaryOperator<Map<P, ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<C, V>>> combiner = (
            l, r) -> {
        l.putAll(r);
        return l;
    };

    final Function<Map<P, ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<C, V>>, ImmutableMap<P, ImmutableMultimap<C, V>>> finisher = map -> map
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    toImmutableMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()
                            .build()));

    return Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}
```